# Replace null object with Subschema in a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, replace, null, schema

I want to replace a `null` value in a JSON object with a subschema.

I want to change

```
"format": null
```

to

```
"format": {
    "dateFormat": "dayShortMonthYear"
}
```

Using the code below, I get the following result for `"format":` (which I don't think is correct):

```
"format": "{\"dateFormat\": \"dayShortMonthYear\"}",
```

This is my code. Any help will be greatly apreciated.

```
import json

data_from_api = """{
"response_code": 200,
  "train_number": "12229",
  "position": "at Source",
  "route": [
    {
      "no": 1,
      "has_arrived": false,
      "has_departed": false,
      "schdep": "22:15",
      "actarr": "00:00",
      "distance": "0",
      "day": 0,
      "format": null
    },
    {
      "actdep": "23:40",
      "scharr": "23:38",
      "schdep": "23:40",
      "actarr": "23:38",
      "no": 2,
      "has_departed": false,
      "scharr_date": "15 Nov 2015",
      "has_arrived": false,
      "station": "HRI",
      "distance": "101",
      "actarr_date": "15 Nov 2015",
      "day": 0,
      "format": {
              "dateFormat": "dayShortMonthYear"
      }
    }
  ]
}"""

info = json.loads(data_from_api)
for route in info["route"]:
    if route["format"] is None:
        print json.dumps(route, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
        route["format"] = '{"dateFormat": "dayShortMonthYear"}'
        print json.dumps(route, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: That's the correct result - you're explicitly inserting a *string*. If you want it to be an actual object, you should do `route["format"] = {'dateFormat': 'dayShortMonthYear'}`.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the fix here (and instantly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning format to a string,
just remove the quotes and it should work.

```
route["format"] = {"dateFormat": "dayShortMonthYear"}
```